# Merge hstore data from multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, hstore

Imagine I have a table with this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  values HSTORE NOT NULL
);
```

Imagine I insert a few records and end up with the following:

```
values
-----------------------------
"a"=>"string1","b"=>"string2"
"b"=>"string2","c"=>"string3"
```

Is there any way I can make an aggregate query that will give me a new hstore with the merged keys (and values) for all rows.

Pseudo-query:

```
SELECT hstore_sum(values) AS value_sum FROM test;
```

Desired result:

```
value_sum
--------------------------------------------
"a"=>"string1","b"=>"string2","c"=>"string3"
```

I am aware of potential conflicts with different values for each key, but in my case the order / priority of which value is picked is not important (it does not even have to be deterministic, as they will be the same for the same key).

Is this possible out of the box or do you have to use some specific homemade SQL functions or other to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a lot of things, f.ex:

My first thought was to use the [`each()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) function, and aggregate keys and values separately, like:

```
SELECT  hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
FROM    test,
LATERAL each(hs);
```

But this performs the worst.

You can use the [`hstore_to_array()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) function too, to build a key-value altering array, like ([@JakubKania](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25849761/1499698)):

```
SELECT  hstore(array_agg(altering_pairs))
FROM    test,
LATERAL unnest(hstore_to_array(hs)) altering_pairs;
```

But this isn't perfect yet.

You can rely the `hstore` values' representation, and build up a string, which will contain all your pairs:

```
SELECT  hstore(string_agg(nullif(hs::text, ''), ','))
FROM    test;
```

This is quite fast. However, if you want, you can use a [custom aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html) (which can use the built-in `hstore` concatenation):

```
CREATE AGGREGATE hstore_sum (hstore) (
    SFUNC = hs_concat(hstore, hstore),
    STYPE = hstore
);

-- i used the internal function (hs_concat) for the concat (||) operator,
-- if you do not want to rely on this function,
-- you could easily write an equivalent in a custom SQL function

SELECT hstore_sum(hs)
FROM   test;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/acc9c/15)

Comment: How does it work with an "internal" function? Also, do I need to create the AGGREGATE function on each connection or just one time? (Like CREATE EXTENSION hstore is a one-time thing).

Comment: @ChristianP. *internal* (in this context) means it is not documented. The `hstore` documentation lists the concatenation operator `||` but not its underlying function (`hs_concat`). This should mean normally, that the creators of `hstore` wants their users to use the operator, instead of the function (f.ex. because that function *could* be an implementation detail). -- Yes, you need to declare the aggregate function only once - like normal user-defined functions - and use it every time, you want.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. My only worry is that the internal function gets renamed, changed, etc. whereas I assume they keep functions the same for parity reasons between versions. It works as expected though now :)

Comment: @ChristianP. if you worry, you could create a custom function for that purpose, f.ex. `CREATE FUNCTION hstore_concat(hstore, hstore) RETURNS hstore LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT $1 || $2';`

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for the (very) complete answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no in built function for that but hstore offers a few functions that allow to transform it to something else, for example an array. So we cast it to array, merge the arrays and create hstore from final array:

```
SELECT hstore(array_agg(x)) FROM 
(SELECT unnest(hstore_to_array(hs)) AS x
  FROM test)
as q;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cb11a/1

P.S. Some other combination (like going with JSON) might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote which works in production now. I avoid excessive conversion between types e.g. `hstore` and `array`. I also don't use `hs_concat` as `sfunc` directly as it will pruduce `NULL` if any of the hashes it is aggregating is `NULL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.agg_hstore_sum_sfunc(state hstore, val hstore)
RETURNS hstore AS $$
BEGIN
    IF val IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF state IS NULL THEN
            state := val;
        ELSE
            state := state || val;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN state;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE AGGREGATE public.sum(hstore) (
    SFUNC = public.agg_hstore_sum_sfunc,
    STYPE = hstore
);
```